# Using VBA Excel to create a gramatically correct list

Tags: excel, vba, list

I need to find a way to write a list using ',' and 'and' in the correct manner based on a varying number of items in a list. See demo below:

```
Apples + Oranges + Bananas = Apples, Oranges and Bananas
Apples + Oranges + Pineapples + Bananas = Apples, Oranges, Pineapples and Bananas
Apples + Oranges = Apples and Oranges
```

My first guess would be to create a list or array of values then use some kind of 'n-1' or 'last' function to place the word 'AND' between the last two items and place the symbol ',' between all other items.

Unfortunately I am still fairly new to VBA so haven't been able to make much headway, any guidance or code greatly appreciated.

Best wishes,

Garth
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1nkN.png)

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: No oxford comma, eh?

Comment: My list can have up to 9 different items and are selected for by a user form. I need them to produce a text in a cell that uses ',' and 'and' appropriately.

Comment: Bruce, if you could show me an alternative that uses the Oxford comma I would happily upgrade my sloppy grammar. To give some context to my problem I am trying to use VBA to automate the writing of a legal document and the title is dependant on components are selected.

Comment: How will the list be in Excel? Will a cell have a single word (like in my Formula answer below), or would a cell literally have `Apples + Bananas` or `Apples + Bananas + Bononos`?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1nkN.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with a formula (I know you're asking for VBA...), you can use this one:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A1:D1)=2,A1&" and "&B1,TEXTJOIN($A$5:$B$5,TRUE,A1:D1))
```

In `A5`, put just a comma and a space. In `B5`, put `, and` (note there's a space after `and`).

[image]

Edit: I'll work on a VBA answer..but keep this, since I learned you can have multiple delimiters within a single `TEXTJOIN()`, which I didn't know!

Edit2: After seeing your data, you can still use a formula.  Again, put the `,` and `, and` somewhere (I used `A8:B8` here):

Enter this as an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN($A$8:$B$8,TRUE,IF(B1:B4="YES",A1:A4,""))
```

[image]

And VBA (cheating a little, since I'm just using that formula, but it works):

```
Sub t()
Dim output As String
output = Evaluate("=TEXTJOIN($A$8:$B$8,TRUE,IF(B1:B4=""YES"",A1:A4,""""))")
End Sub
```

Comment: Added a link of what the data looks like. Thank you for the Excel formula, interesting way to approach it.